# How to convert dd.mm.yyyy date in sql table on the fly with sql request and get date less than

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

So I have table, with 'date' column. Data type is varchar. I want to get date that greater than curdate. In column date i have dates in format dd.mm.yyyy, so I need to convert it before make `>=`. How to do that right?

```
SELECT * 
FROM online_plan 
WHERE 
    CONVERT(datetime, date, 104) >= CURDATE() 
    AND squad = '10' 
    AND status !='opened'
```

- doesn't work

Comment: Why not store dates as a proper datatype? Use `date` or `datetime` columns for dates, not varchars..

Comment: that is another question:). Can we solve cur. task?:)

Comment: I'm not sure which your problem is... besides you are storing dates as varchar...

Comment: is there way to convert from varchar to date on the fly with one request, as my example?

Comment: Sure you can! Did you try it? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Why do you want to convert on the fly. Just convert your column to DATE and store the values in native format.

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work?* Are you getting an error, which one?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That query is product specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CONVERT(datetime, date, 104) >= CURDATE()

You seem to be mixing MySQL and SQL Server syntax.

---

On the one hand, [`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a legitimate SQL Server function, but `CURDATE()` does not exists in that RDBMS; you would need to use [`GETDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead, as follows:

```
CONVERT(datetime, date, 104) >= GETDATE()
```

[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=064c3a069774d4ba09eea05871e463f2)

---

On the other hand, MySQL does support [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) but not `CONVERT()`; you need [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') >= CURDATE()
```

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5fd36f33483d5c19267db8ebf443bbd1)